# SP Initiated SingleLogout throws "HTTP Form does not contain SAMLRequest"

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I'm using the latest ITFoxTec nuget package and have implemented the endpoints as your example on the website shows.

Our customer is requiring us to trigger the singlelogout from our portal instead of the regular logout endpoint that works just fine.
When we trigger the singlelogout endpoint instead it is throwing an exception with the message: "HTTP Form does not contain SAMLRequest"

I understand that when the IDP triggers this endpoint it is sending the SAMLRequest... to me it doesn't seem like this is something that we can send from our portal without extensive coding, so it seems a bit unreasonable from the customer to ask for us to use the singlelogout endpoint instead of the regular logout.

Is there a way to configure the metadata file or somewhere in the NemId administration portal for the singlelogout endpoint to be triggered every time the regular logout is being triggered? Just like loggedout is being triggered?

What can we do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must only call the logout endpoint which call the IdP to request logout. Only the IdP can call the single logout endpoint.

If there are multible applications logged in at the samme time. The IdP use the single logout endpoint to subsequently log out all applications, if one application start the logout sequence with a logout request.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out eventually, the customer was wrong...
Thanks for your help Anders!